# How to access SAPI 4 voices from .net framework 3.5

Tags: .net, sapi

I’m trying to use a SAPI 4 engine (L&H TTS 3000) from .net 3.5 using System.Speech.Synthesis in windows XP.

The problem is than I can only get SAPI 5.1 engines when I call GetInstalledVoices.

I’m using SAPI 4 because I need a Spanish TTS engine and L&H TTS 3000 is the only one free that I have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't - System.Speech.Synthesis relies on SAPI 5.1, and SAPI 5.1 can't use SAPI 4 TTS engines.

Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Using VISTA OR WIN7 64 bits with VB6
You can use sapi 4 components and the character of Merlin  without any problem.

First install Merlin Programmer for Kids v.5.5.8.msi
http://www.scisoftco.com/merlin/installation.html
Once this is done go to the configuration panel and display "small icons" => choose "Speech"
and see which languages are installed.
If you need French for instance, you will need AgtX040CFrench.exe and lhttsfrfFrench.exe
After installing those 2 , you can hear Merlin speaking French or any language (Spanish, Dutch, British English..)